# How can I import local modules from my .xmonad/xmonad.hs

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to import a custom, local module named 'Tree.hs' from ~/.xmonad/Tree.hs, but I get:

```
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/shahn/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:55:8:
    Could not find module ‘Tree’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Please check the file for errors.
```

It seems that ghc doesn't search in ~/.xmonad for modules. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xmonad searches for modules in the `~/.xmonad/lib` directory. Just put your module in there.

http://xmonad.org/manpage.html#modular-configuration